# Accounting result not getting printed correctly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

Following code should be supposed to print out the value of `Sum3` when the given string is equals to `N`.

But instead of printing the value of `Sum3` it prints `er` irrespective of the value of String given.

When I remove the `if-else` block it works fine. Could someone help me in fixing this issue?

Here is my code:

```
double myInt1 = input.nextDouble();
double myInt2 = input.nextDouble();
double myInt3 = input.nextDouble();
String cmsc = input.nextLine();

double Sum= ((myInt2 * 60)+myInt3)/(3600);
double Sum2=myInt1+Sum;

if(cmsc.equals("N"))
{
    double Sum3= -1*Sum2;
    System.out.println(Sum3);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("er");
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
N
```

Expected Output:

```
-1.0341666666666667
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with both java and javascript?

Comment: Most likely, `cmsc` is not "N". I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to help find the bug in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting anything in `cmsc` with your existing code as by doing `input.nextLine();` you are just going to the next line.

You should be adding `input.nextLine();` after taking the input in `myInt3` and then take any input in `cmsc` by doing `String cmsc = input.nextLine();`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
double myInt1 = input.nextDouble();
double myInt2 = input.nextDouble();
double myInt3 = input.nextDouble();
/* Goto Next Line */
input.nextLine();
/* Now take input in cmsc */
String cmsc = input.nextLine();
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
N
```

Output:

```
-1.0341666666666667
```